# Incompatible block pointer type 'void (^)()NSUInteger *(*)(int))' to 'void(^)(int)'

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I am attempting to send a number (0, 1, 2, 3 or 4) as a callback to a function in MasterViewController.h and am using an int to send that data from Snapchat.h

Here is the code in my MasterViewController.m

```
[[Snapchat sharedClient] initiateLoginWithUsername:@"USERNAME" password:@"PASSWORD" callback:^(NSUInteger *response(int)){
    //NSLog(@"Stage 1: %@", response);
}];
```

...and here is the code from Snapchat.h

```
-(void)initiateLoginWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password callback:(void (^)(int))callback;
```

But when I build and run, I get an error `Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)()NSUInteger *(*)(int))' to parameter of type 'void(^)(int)'` on the code provided for MasterViewController.m

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this `^(NSUInteger *response(int)` statement with `^(int response)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I'll accept the answer once time restrictions have been lifted.(: